# springboot mongo if image not present use existing one

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

This api works for inserting and updating but everytim I update the image dissapears so I am trying to say orElse if image not exist set image to existing image any advice pls

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateBank", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<Bank> updateBank(
        @RequestPart("bank") @Valid Bank bank,
        @RequestPart("file") @Valid Optional<MultipartFile> image) throws IOException {
    // routine to update a bank including image
    image.ifPresent(pic ->
    {
        try {
            bank.setImage(new Binary(BsonBinarySubType.BINARY, pic.getBytes()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Bank result = bankRepository.save(bank);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);
}

@Document(collection = "mst_Bank")
public class Bank {
        @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String country;
    private String region;
    private String city;
    private String swiftCode;
    private String routeCode;
    private Binary flag;
    private Binary image;

    public Bank(String name, String address, String country, String region, String city, String swiftCode,
                String routeCode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.country = country;
        this.region = region;
        this.city = city;
        this.swiftCode = swiftCode;
        this.routeCode = routeCode;
    }

    public Bank() {

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getSwiftCode() {
        return swiftCode;
    }

    public void setSwiftCode(String swiftCode) {
        this.swiftCode = swiftCode;
    }

    public String getRouteCode() {
        return routeCode;
    }

    public void setRouteCode(String routeCode) {
        this.routeCode = routeCode;
    }

    public Binary getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Binary image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


}
```

/*No Point of this
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.*/

Comment: Can you add the source for Bank class as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateEntity", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<Entity> updateEntity(@RequestPart("entity") @Valid Entity entity, @RequestPart("file") @Valid Optional<MultipartFile> image) throws IOException {

// routine to update a entity including image
        byte[] imageData = null;
        if (image.isPresent() && image.get() != null)
            imageData = image.get().getBytes();
        if (imageData == null && entity.getId() != null) {
            Optional<Entity> readEntity = entityRepository.findById(entity.getId());
            if (readEntity.get() != null)
                imageData = readEntity.get().getImage().getData();
        }
        if (imageData != null) {
            entity.setImage(new Binary(BsonBinarySubType.BINARY, imageData));
        }
        Entity result = entityRepository.save(entity);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);

    }
```